# How to print out custom JSON object values after they have be downloaded?

Tags: json, swift, nsurlsession

I have a custom object:

```
class SampleJSON {

  var costDictionary: [String: Any]
  var airbnbDetails: [String: Any]
  var airbnbUS: Int
  var airbnbLocal: Int

  init(costDictionary: [String: Any], airbnbDetails: [String: Any], airbnbUS: Int, airbnbLocal: Int){

    self.costDictionary = costDictionary
    self.airbnbDetails = airbnbDetails
    self.airbnbUS = airbnbUS
    self.airbnbLocal = airbnbLocal
}

init(resultsDictionary:[String: Any]){

    costDictionary = (resultsDictionary["cost"] as? [String: Any])!
    airbnbDetails = (costDictionary["airbnb_median"] as? [String: Any])!
    airbnbUS = (airbnbDetails["USD"] as? Int)!
    airbnbLocal = (airbnbDetails["CHF"] as? Int)!
}
```

I'm trying to print out the value of the objects after they have been downloaded:

```
  static func downloadAllTableViewData(urlExtension:String) -> [SampleJSON] {

    var sampleJSON = [SampleJSON]()//array of custom object

    let usm = UrlSessionNetworkManager.sharedManager

    if let jsonDictionary = usm.parseJSONFromData(urlExtension:urlExtension)

    {
      let resultDictionaries = jsonDictionary["result"] as! [[String : Any]]
      for resultsDictionary in resultDictionaries {// enumerate through dictionary
        let nomadInfo = SampleJSON(resultsDictionary: resultsDictionary)

        sampleJSON.append(nomadInfo)
      }
    } else {
      print("Error: Cannot retrieve JSON Data")
    }

    print(sampleJSON) //Print Data here

    return sampleJSON
  }
}
```

I'm trying to print out all the values of the custom object but when I try use print(sampleJSON) all I get printed out to console is

> MyProject.SampleJSON

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I guess you should print `resultsDictionary` instead, before `init` of your own class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `description` variable to your `SampleJSON` class, and make it conform to `CustomStringConvertible`. For example:

```
class SampleJSON: CustomStringConvertible {

  var costDictionary: [String: Any]
  var airbnbDetails: [String: Any]
  var airbnbUS: Int
  var airbnbLocal: Int

  init(costDictionary: [String: Any], airbnbDetails: [String: Any], airbnbUS: Int, airbnbLocal: Int){

    self.costDictionary = costDictionary
    self.airbnbDetails = airbnbDetails
    self.airbnbUS = airbnbUS
    self.airbnbLocal = airbnbLocal
  }

  init(resultsDictionary:[String: Any]){

    costDictionary = (resultsDictionary["cost"] as? [String: Any])!
    airbnbDetails = (costDictionary["airbnb_median"] as? [String: Any])!
    airbnbUS = (airbnbDetails["USD"] as? Int)!
    airbnbLocal = (airbnbDetails["CHF"] as? Int)!
  }

  var description: String {
    return "SampleJSON(cost: \(self.costDictionary), airbnb: \(self.airbnbDetails), airbnb US: \(self.airbnbUS), airbnb local: \(self.airbnbLocal))"
  }
}
```

Comment: That worked! I wish I knew about this earlier.  Thanks for your help!